# Finding maximum weight arborescence in an edge-weighted DAG

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms

Let $G$ be an edge-weighted DAG with a unique source $s$. The question is how to find out a maximum weight arborescence in $G$ rooted at $s$.

When all edge weights are positive then the required arborescence is also spanning and so we can use the directed minimum spanning tree algorithm (http://www.ce.rit.edu/~sjyeec/dmst.html)

What if negative weights are allowed?

Comment: do you want the tree to be arborescence? or undirected tree?

Comment: arborescence rooted at $s$

Comment: Please edit your question so that people do not have to read the comments to understand what is being asked.

Comment: Aren't arborescence and directed tree both rooted at $s$ the same thing in DAG.?

Comment: @Imran: The comment by Webbisshh suggests that the use of the word “subtree” in the question (whether it means a directed tree or an undirected tree) can be ambiguous, at least to some people.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Agreed, I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is NP-complete by a reduction from the set cover problem.

**Set cover**
*Instance*: A finite set *U*, a family *C* of subsets of *U* and *k*∈ℕ.
*Question*: Is there a cover *D* of *U* in *C* with at most *k* sets, that is, a subset *D* of *C* with |*D*|≤*k* such that the union of *D* is equal to *U*?

Given an instance (*U*, *C*, *k*) of the set cover problem, let *U*={*a*<sub>1</sub>, …, *a*<sub>*n*</sub>} and *C*={*S*<sub>1</sub>, …, *S*<sub>*m*</sub>} (*n*=|*U*|, *m*=|*C*|) and construct a DAG *G* with four layers of vertices:

- The first layer consists of a single source *s*.
- The second layer consists of *m* vertices *x*<sub>1</sub>, …, *x*<sub>*m*</sub>, each of which has an incoming edge from *s* with weight −1.
- The third layer consists of *n* vertices *y*<sub>1</sub>, …, *y*<sub>*n*</sub>.  The vertex *y*<sub>*i*</sub> has an incoming edge from the vertex *x*<sub>*j*</sub> with weight 0 for each pair (*i*, *j*) such that *a*<sub>*i*</sub>∈*S*<sub>*j*</sub>.
- The fourth layer consists of *n* vertices *z*<sub>1</sub>, …, *z*<sub>*n*</sub>.  Each vertex *z*<sub>*i*</sub> has an incoming edge from the corresponding vertex *y*<sub>*i*</sub> with weight *m*.

Then it is easy to see that there is a cover of *U* in *C* with at most *k* sets if and only if the DAG *G* has an arborescence rooted at *s* with total weight at least *nm*−*k*.

Comment: Clever! Do you mind if I put it into the [original proof list](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/784/1800)? Or do you think it is at the level of an observation?

Comment: @Hsien-Chih: Thanks.  Not sure this time. :)  But it may have appeared in the literature, so probably it is better to wait for a while anyway.

Comment: Many thanks Tsuyoshi for the elegant proof! I had the intution that the problem must be NP-complete, but somehow couldn't prove it.

Answer (score 0):

What about picking, for any vertex different from the source, an incoming arc with maximum weight ? Each vertex except the source is of indegree one, and you needn't worry about circuits as you are in a DAG.

Comment: This works when all edge weights are positive. With negative weight, we may need to discard some of the nodes.

Comment: Oops ! Got it :-)